# Spreecommerce files location

Tags: spree

I like to deploy the Spreecommerce locally and want to implement my own changes. I have deployed successfully but I don't know where the actual sources files comes or running. I need help to sort this out. Please can any one help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: please provide us more informations.  What do you mean with " I don't know where the actual sources files comes or running"?

Answer (score 1):

Bundler downloads dependent gems into a cache location, but you don't want to mess with that if you're looking to make code changes.  Anything you change there will be lost later when you update your gems.

You'll want to familiarize yourself with the standard rails customization methods.  In order of least-to-most intrusive:

- Decorators - files in your host application's app folder structure (assets, controllers, models, overrides, views, etc) which change a single method on Spree's objects by using the syntax `Spree::[whatever class].class_eval do` and then using standard ruby method definitions (followed by `end`).  These files match their Spree counterpart in the same folder, just in your app instead of Spree's source.  And with `_decorator` added to the end of the filename.  See an example here: https://github.com/binaryphile/spree_dibs_1.2/blob/master/app/controllers/spree/admin/payments_controller_decorator.rb
- Overriding entire Spree files - copy the Spree source file to the same location in your app then make the necessary source changes.  This will override Spree's file of the same name (no `_decorator` this time).  You're taking responsibility for migrating all future code changes by Spree to that file into your copy, which is why this is less desirable.
- Fork the Spree source - change your Gemfile reference to your version instead of Spree.  Make your changes to this code directly and run it instead of regular Spree.  This is highly undesirable, as it makes upgrading Spree versions very involved and difficult.

If you're planning on making the code reusable, you could also investigate making it into an internal or published extension.  See the Spree docs on that approach.

Comment: Here I have a query ! 

In spree commerce official website, they have added a custom action under the HomeController; But How We can know what controller names have been used inside Spree Project  ? 

Any way to deploy the project or any way to list out what Model, View & Controllers have been used in the Spree Application ?

Comment: Thanks for the info - but users finding this should know what I just discovered, the "spree gem" is where the files exist.  Would it make sense to just copy the entire thing into the "normal" directory tree, so one can work with this, ummm, like a "Rails app"?  Also, the link to the github in this answer appears to be gone - which is why such things need to be copied into answers.

Comment: Link is updated, my github username had changed.  Try it now.  Wrt to copying files into your tree, that's the least maintainable approach, but you are welcome to use it of course.